# Latex table formatting

Tags: tables

I am trying to add a table like below in Latex. Can anyone please help?

[image: Table]

Here is the one I have:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

{\columncolor{2}{green!80!yellow!50}{green!70!yellow!40}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1cm}|p{1cm} |p{1cm}|p{1cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{t = 5} \\
\hline
Selection & EC  & Selection & EC  \\
\hline
AF & AF & Selection & EC  \\
Ala    & ALA & Selection & EC  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
    \end{document}
```

However, this alters row color instead of column and also I am unable to add other columns.

UPDATE:

I am trying below code as posted by Bernerd:

```
\begin{tabular}{ || *{2}{>{\columncolor{blue!30!white!50}}p{1.5cm}| >{\columncolor{white}}p{1.5cm}|| }}
\hline
\rowcolor{white} \multicolumn{2}{||c|}{t = 5} & \multicolumn{2}{||c||}{t = 10}  \\
\hline
\hline
Selection & EC & Selection & EC \\
\hline
Afghan & AF & Afghan & AF\\
Aland  & ALA & Aland  & ALA \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, the column separating lines are not aligned!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post a compilable document showing what you've managed to do so far?

Comment: `\multicolumn`and `colortbl` might be interesting for you.

Comment: You might want to use `\columncolor` instead or `\rowcolor`. To add more columns, add as many column specifiers as neede (for example `lll` for three left aligned columns or `|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|` for three columns that are 3 cm wide and are separated by vertical lines.

Comment: Please also reconsider if using `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}` is really a good idea as this will give you extremely wide lines and also quite a lot of empty space aroudn the contents of each cell. If your table will contain 11 columns, you will most likely not fit it onto a page with these settings.

Comment: I have removed those lines and tried to use \columncolor. It gives me an error in overleaf. Also, I am still unable to add extra columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, booktabs}
\begin{document}

{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ |l |*{2}{>{\columncolor{green!80!yellow!50}}p{2.2cm} >{\columncolor{green!50!yellow!40}}p{2.3cm}| }}
\hline
\rowcolor{white} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries t = 5} & & \\
\hhline{|~|>{\arrayrulecolor{Aquamarine}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{Aquamarine}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|} 
Packet & Selection & EC & Selection & EC \\
\hhline{|~|>{\arrayrulecolor{Aquamarine}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{Aquamarine}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
Switching & Afghanistan & AF & Afghanistan & AF\\
\arrayrulecolor{Aquamarine}\midrule[1.2pt] \arrayrulecolor{black}
Energy & Aland Islands & ALA &Aland Islands & ALA \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 }

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I can't add more column like the fig in my questions. Also, I don't know how to add the leftmost column without any heading.

Comment: @leandriis: Thanks for editing!

Comment: @jhon_wick: I've modified my code. Is it more like you want?

Comment: Thanks. I only need the leftmost columns as shown in the picture.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the exact layou you want: the leftmost column should not be coloured, with an empty head, then the other columns should follow a pattern of two colours, with the  first row non-coloured, and vertical lines only at both ends of  the pattern, but not between the columns inside the pattern?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I am trying to do. Also, using your code, I am getting non-aligned vertical lines in the 1st row. I have updated the code.

Comment: I've modified my codde. As you can see, the vertical lines are aligned. If it happens again for you please post the code you use.